# Window Explorer shows only Arrange by Author

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

When I browse to Libraries > Documents the "Arrange by:" dropdown at the top right of the selected folder pane shows only "Arrange by: Author". All the other options e.g. Date Modified, Tag, Type, Name are disabled.

I would rather just view files by their name.

How can I enable this and other "Arrange by" options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I finally managed to fix this by removing the existing Libraries > Documents and creating a new one using the **Shell Library Command Line** (ShLib.exe)

```
@echo off

c:
cd <your folder containing shlib.exe>
shlib create "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms"
shlib add "%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Libraries\Documents.library-ms" %HOMESHARE%

pause
```